# C Unix Xcode bug again

Tags: c, linux, xcode, unix, semaphore

I am doing a university project, we have to use the Unix system call.
Right now, I'm really struggling to understand if, in my project, there really is a mistake. This is because, while in terminal it compiles and it starts and finishes without error, on xcode I get several errors.

In particular, I get errors when using semaphores.

I'll try to explain what errors, I receive, but since I'm not native English speakers forgive me in advance if I make some mistakes.

First, the program creates a number of child processes with a fork (). It does depending on how many clientei.txt located (i = iterator).
Immediately I block parent with a semaphore, I run the child up to a certain point, then I block it with a semaphore and I restart the parent.

At this point, the parent should read a message sent by his son, call a function to print the content inside a log.txt and restart the son.

Then the child does other things (including erase the message) and it block.
The parent restart, and everything is repeated for subsequent children.

While in terminal synchronization is perfect (everything happens at the right time without error) this both Linux and Mac, about XCode I had several errors:

semop: Resource temporarily unavailable (if I created more than 5 txt)
semop: File too large (if I created more than 2)

with 2 instead gave me two errors:
semop 1: Interrupted system call (this stops after running both processes)
semop 3: Identifier removed (with this in restarting the second process)

is not so much time that I do C then I do not know what to do. I would like first of all to know if I have to worry (so there is an error), or I have to be quiet because it is a bug in xcode.
If there was a mistake I kindly ask you not to ask me to change the code a lot.
This is mainly because they are close to expiring and I can not afford to do it all again.
I also ask you, if you can, to be as clear as possible. I understand enough English, but not as a mother-tongue, I can not always follow the responses here on StackOverflow.

The code is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2utsb6r5d7kzzqj/xcode%2Bterminal.zip?dl=0
this zip contain a small part of the project that has this problem.
the terminal version works. there is a makefile in this version to simplify the compilation.
xcode version does not work. It contains the Debug folder. Indeed xcode, txt files, it does not read from the root folder where the codes are contained in the folder where it creates the compiled. There is a readme in each case with the procedure in detail.

I tried to minimize, I commented all in English.
I removed the code that was not needed, but I added the file with all the include and functions that use.

here the code:

### main.c

```
    key_t key, key_2;
    int semid, semid_2;
    union semun arg;
    union semun arg_2;
    struct sembuf sb_2 = {0, -1, 0};
    char* nome_file;
    nome_file = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*));
    int numero_clienti;

    //semaphore for all the child
    struct sembuf sb[numero_clienti];

    int i_c;
    for (i_c = 0; i_c < numero_clienti; i_c++) {
        sb[i_c].sem_num = i_c;
        sb[i_c].sem_op = -1;
        sb[i_c].sem_flg = 0;

    }
    //cretion of first SEMAPHORE
    {
        //key creation
        if ((key = ftok("cliente0.txt", 'J')) == -1)
        {
            perror("ftok");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //creation of the semaphore
        if ((semid = semget(key, numero_clienti, 0666 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL)) == -1)
        {
            perror("semget");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //set value of all child semaphore
        for (i_c = 0; i_c < numero_clienti; i_c++) {
            arg.val = 0;
            if (semctl(semid, i_c, SETVAL, arg) == -1)
            {
                perror("semctl");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

    }
    //cretion of second SEMAPHORE
    {
        //key creation
        if ((key_2 = ftok("cliente1.txt", 'J')) == -1)
        {
            perror("ftok");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //creation of the semaphore
        if ((semid_2 = semget(key_2, 1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL)) == -1)
        {
            perror("semget");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //set value of parent semaphore
        arg_2.val = 0;
        if (semctl(semid_2, 0, SETVAL, arg_2) == -1)
        {
            perror("semctl");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    while(fd > 0 && pid > 0){


        j++;

        close(fd);
        pid = fork();

        if(pid != 0)
        {
            i++;
            sprintf(nome_file, "./cliente%d.txt", i);
            fd = open(nome_file, O_RDONLY);
        }
        switch(pid)
        {
            //error case
            case -1:
            {
                perror("Error during fork.");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                break;
            }
            //child case
            case 0:
            {

                puts("Child: I'm a child");
                messaggio(numero_clienti, j);
                puts("Child: I have to do something");

                //Start parent
                sb_2.sem_op = 1;
                if (semop(semid_2, &sb_2, 1) == -1)
                {
                    perror("semop");
                    exit(1);
                }
                //, stop itself
                sb[j].sem_op = -1;
                if (semop(semid, &sb[j], 1) == -1)
                {
                    perror("semop");
                    exit(1);
                }

                printf("Child: I have to do something else %d\n", getpid());

                _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                break;
            }
            //parent case
            default:
            {

                puts("Parent: I'm a parent");

                //Stop itself
                sb_2.sem_op = -1;
                if (semop(semid_2, &sb_2, 1) == -1)
                {
                    perror("semop padre");
                    exit(1);
                }

                puts("Parent: now I can send the message, my child is blocked");

                //restart child
                sb[j].sem_op = 1;
                if (semop(semid, &sb[j], 1) == -1)
                {
                    perror("semop");
                    exit(1);
                }
                //stop itself
                sb_2.sem_op = -1;
                if (semop(semid_2, &sb_2, 1) == -1)
                {
                    perror("semop");
                    exit(1);
                }

                puts("Parent: end of while");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    puts("Parent: I can restart all my child");

    for (i_c = 0; i_c < numero_clienti; i_c++) {
        sb[i_c].sem_op = 1;
        if (semop(semid, &sb[i_c], 1) == -1)
        {
            perror("semop");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    puts("I wait the end of my child...");
    while (wait(NULL) != -1);

    puts("All child end");

    //remove semaphore I create
    if (semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID, arg) == -1)
    {
        perror("semctl");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (semctl(semid_2, 0, IPC_RMID, arg_2) == -1)
    {
        perror("semctl");
        exit(1);
    }

    puts("FINE");
    return 0;

}
```

### cliente.c

```
#include "cliente.h"

/**
 inside this function child do some thing.
 1. at this point it give control to parent after it create a message
 2. at this point it remove the message
 */
void messaggio(int numero_clienti, int num_j){
    key_t key, key_2;
    int semid, semid_2;
    struct sembuf sb[numero_clienti];
    int i_c;
    for (i_c = 0; i_c < numero_clienti; i_c++) {
        sb[i_c].sem_num = i_c;
        sb[i_c].sem_op = -1;
        sb[i_c].sem_flg = 0;

    }
    struct sembuf sb_2 = {0, -1, 0};

    if ((key = ftok("cliente0.txt", 'J')) == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((semid = semget(key, 1, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("semget");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((key_2 = ftok("cliente1.txt", 'J')) == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((semid_2 = semget(key_2, 1, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("semget");
        exit(1);
    }
    //creation of a message
    //1. Restart parent
    sb_2.sem_op = 1;
    if (semop(semid_2, &sb_2, 1) == -1)
    {
        perror("semop");
        exit(1);
    }

    puts("cambio sem");
    //stop itself
    sb[num_j].sem_op = -1;
    if (semop(semid, &sb[num_j], 1) == -1)
    {
        perror("semop");
        exit(1);
    }
    //here it can move again
    puts("remove message");

    puts("Figlio: sono tornato attivo, mio padre aspetta");

}
```

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it's minimal, complete and verifiable. It also have makefile to test. I cannot make less minimal. If I do it will be incomplete

Comment: TL;DR! Please edit your question to include only the relevant code, if we need to see more we will ask for it. As for the errors, please provide actual (and expected) output.

Comment: It's far from minimal.

Comment: now there is only main and cliente. the error are:semop: Resource temporarily unavailable (if I created more than 5 txt) semop: File too large (if I created more than 2). 

with 2 instead gave me two errors: semop 1: Interrupted system call (this stops after running both processes) semop 3: Identifier removed (with this in restarting the second process)ONLY IN XCODE

Comment: And you need to check for errors from *all* system calls, even ones you don't think can fail (like some `read` calls, some `open` calls, possible `close` calls, etc.) And remember that the current directory is seldom the same in an IDE as when run from the console.

Comment: how can I make it more minimal without give you an incomplete code? I can't.

Comment: I can try to delete all non-semaphore code

Comment: The code doesn't *have* to be complete, only *relevant*!

Comment: ok. "Please provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" well. I delete all non-semaphore code. You can download the complete code from dropbox. Now it's ok?

Comment: I just pulled your sources, compiled and ran the code in dir/ `model terminal` under Linux. There seem to be memory management issues. Run the program using a memory checkler likme Valgrind (http://valgrind.org) and you will see.

Comment: thank you alk I'll try to use Valgrind

Comment: Also: Do yourself a favor and compile using `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g`!

Comment: ok. I used already -Wall but I did not know about the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st you do

```
nome_file = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

which allocates 4 or 8 bytes (depending on the platform you compile on: 32 or 64bit).

Then you do

```
sprintf(nome_file, "./cliente%d.txt", i);
```

The latter writes to invalid memory, as `"./cliente%d.txt"` is 14+1 characters long plus the potenial number of digits from `i` if `i>9` or and addtional sign if `i<0`.

To fix this allocate what is needed:

```
nome_file = malloc(13 + 10 + 1 + 1); /* 13 for the filename, 
                                        10 for the digits, 
                                         1 for a potential sign, 
                                         1 the C-"strings" 0-terminator. */
```

This is a really ugly bug, which is expected to be the main issue in your code.

---

*Also* in the sources (you linked) in function `read_line()` you allocate memory, which you do not properly initialise, but later depend on its content.

main.c:20

```
char* myb2 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

`malloc()` does not initialise the memory it allocates, so either do:

```
char * myb2 = calloc(1, sizeof(char*));
```

of add and addtional call to

```
memset(mb2, 0, sizeof(char*));
```

after the call to `malloc()`.

This bug is nasty either.

---

*Also^2* you should build using gcc's options `-std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE`.

That is because:

1. You are using C constructs available from C99 on only. Typically VLAs, so tell the compiler to treat the code as being C99 code by explcitly stating `-std=c99`
2. To `#define` `_XOPEN_SOURCE` is issued by gcc, for some header you include in your project.

---

*Also^3* you seem to be not necessarily count the correct number of client(file)s, at least not if your files a distributed as per the archive you linked:

main.c:82

```
system("ls cliente* | wc -l");
```

Change this to be:

```
system("ls cliente*.txt | wc -l");
```

If the bug described above should return more files then there actually are the following code fails as well from a certain value of `i` on:

main.c:176

```
fd = open(nome_file, O_RDONLY);
```

The result of the above operation is *NOT* tested. The possible invalid `fd` is used and the infamous undefined behaviour is taking over. Everything can happen.

---

As a final note: It's mostly *never* a bug in the tools we are using.

Comment: You do not worry, I have not learned much from C I expected some stupid mistake, indeed many thanks for letting me know.
Now I'll try to test it.

Comment: Sorry can you explain more? Why "The latter writes to invalid memory." what I need to do. Also why use -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE

Comment: do you mean something like this?nome_file = (char*) malloc((sizeof(char*))*14); Can't I have a string of any size?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not going to say that you have answered my question because it is not true.
Before you spoke of an allocation invalid in "nome_file" but you did not say how I should solve. Then you told me that I should compile with -STD = c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -Wextra -pedantic -g without explaining why.
You told me not in read_line initialize () without explaining how would you have done, or give me an example.
I thank you because you were the only one to try and help me out, and also for introducing me to Valgrind. But you have not answered my question.

Comment: nome_file do you mean I need to add a free? if yes where?

Comment: Now it's a complete answer. Thank you a lot

Comment: You are welcome, thank Sunday! ;-) `-Wextra` and `-pedantic` justs makes the compiler even more chatty. Thats help for free. Also a tool like Valgrind is *the* essential checker for subtile bugs, which do not make the program crash (immediately). Testing with a tool like Valgrind is a *Must* for any production code. @FrencedereFedere

Comment: I corrected everything that you suggested but continues to give the same problem but only on xcode.
Perhaps there really is a bug, otherwise it would be strange that using terminal continues to work.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I added the section "*Also^3*".

Comment: I thank you for all the advice you gave me. Eventually I discovered several things including the fact that there is a memory checker integrated in xcode (and also how to use valgrind).
But I have discovered that the problem was another. In fact putting all .c .h into the folder of compiled xcode (xcode unlike gcc does not read the txt from the same folder of the source) and magically it all worked out. It seems that for some reason does not have enough space for all the semaphore creat, but the putting into multiple files succeeded.

Comment: also if(fd<0)
 {
  perror("Error during opening of file");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 } it's not enought for test?

Comment: Also really strange. when I try to add .txt to cliente* system("ls cliente* | wc -l"); I gain the same problem again

Comment: I am referring to the `open()` inside the while loop. *Also^4* `open ` can very well return a vlaue of `0`, so `while(fd > 0 && pid > 0)` shall be `while(fd >= 0 && pid > 0)`.

Comment: You are aware that semaphore (as well as shared memory) are *not* released automagically when the program ends? So in case you break your program before the code releasing the semaphores gets called you need to release them by hand.

Comment: I know. ipcrm -q/s/m number of message/semaphore/shared memory.